# Cable modem not working with USB, but works fine with Ethernet

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, modem, cable

I just got cable internet with a cable modem. The guy hooked it up with the ethernet cord, and it works fine, but when I try to use USB with it, it doesn't connect to the internet.

I've gone through several times trying to unplug, wait 10 secs, replug; reset IP address; reset network; etc.. to no avail, but the second I plug my Ethernet cord back in, it connects...

Also, I don't think it's a bad hookup or anything because Windows notifies me that a "jack has been plugged in".

Anyway, I'd really like to do this so I can have my Ethernet cord run from my desktop to my laptop or straight from my cable modem to my laptop (if possible).

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your cable modem supports connecting to the Internet over USB, you may need to install drivers. Find the support site for the cable modem model you are using and look for driver downloads.

I recommend getting a four-port router which will make this a lot simpler. Additionally it will provide things like firewall, wifi (if you get a wireless router), and the ability to connect to the internet from your laptop when your desktop is shut down. They are quite inexpensive these days.

Answer (score 1):

Did you call your ISP? Your cable modem should be covered by contract warranty. They will be able to fix your problem/replace the modem since they know the model, firmware, HAL and other important information.